# text-align/margin-left/etc. not working for my animated header

Tags: css

I have an animated header that is basically one stagnant word and preceeding it is a carousel of many words (in the same position) that fade in and out (thanks to animate.css). I followed a tutorial on youtube to get the basic webpage so it may look familiar or simple. 
However, the preceeding words are stuck in complicated div's and headers to attempt to get multiple animations (enter and exit for each). 
The problem is that when a long word comes onto the screen, it overlaps on the second word.

(Picture included)
[image: enjoyingirelnd]
To explain briefly, the button and text are all in a "display:table;" div and the words were normally just one cohesive sentence and worked fine. However, I've had to split them up and the only way to prevent them from being above/below one another (VERY annoying) was to force them to float left and right. However, when I delete the floats now (after much 'debugging') it doesnt seem to actually change the design, which greatly worries me. I have included my code. Please help! My idea right now is to make the text right aligned and relative to the second word, but everything I try seems to do absolutely nothing. If there are any other solutions I am all ears.

```
<section class="intro">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <section style="clear: both">
                <div style="position:absolute"  z-index="1">
                <h1 z-index="inherit"display="inline-block" class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInDown" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
                    <div text-align="right" z-index="inherit" class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeOutDown" data-os-animation-delay="1s">Loving</div></h1>
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute" margin-left="15%" z-index="2">
                <h1 z-index="inherit" display="inline-block" class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInDown" data-os-animation-delay="1s">
                    <div text-align="right" z-index="inherit" class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeOutDown" data-os-animation-delay="2s">Enjoying</div></h1>
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute"  z-index="3">
                <h1 z-index="inherit"  display="inline-block" class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInDown" data-os-animation-delay="2s">
                    <div text-align="right" z-index="inherit" class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeOutDown" data-os-animation-delay="3s">Exploring</div></h1>
                </div>

                <h1 style="float: right">Irelnd</h1>
            </section>

            <section style="clear:both" class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay="5s">
                <a href="file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/Landing%20Page%20Starter%20Files/index.html" class="btn">Get Started</a>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yantramanav:100');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400');

html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#carousel {
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
#Dubai{
    background-color: red;
}



.intro{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/470641/pexels-photo-470641.jpeg) no-repeat ;

    display: table;
    top:0;
    background-size:cover;

}
.intro .inner{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%;
}
.content{
    max-width:480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 28%;
    padding-left: 4%;
}

.content h1 {
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    font-size: 600%;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #E1efe9;
    line-height: 55%;
}

.btn {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 135%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3c4f1f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid #3c4f1f;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn:hover{
    color: #a0afa8;
    border: solid #a0afa8;
}
p{
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}




/*--- Media Queries --*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .content{
        padding-bottom: 30%;
        max-width: 320px;
    }
    .content h1{
        font-size: 450%;
    }
    .btn{
        font-size: 130%;
        padding: 9px 15px;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content{
        padding-bottom: 40%;
        max-width: 210px;
    }
    .content h1{
        font-size: 300%;
    }
    .btn{
        font-size: 110%;
        padding: 9px 15px;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 120%;
        line-height: 100%;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .content{
        padding-bottom: 50%;
        max-width: 173px;
    }
    .content h1{
        font-size: 250%;
    }
    .btn{
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 4px 12px;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 100%;
        line-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Float will not change your design, because the word on the left is always absolutely positioned and will have no effect on the layout/flow of its siblings (in this case, the word on the right). Can you create an MCVE?

Comment: I don't know what an MCVE is, I'm sorry. 
I don't want it to affect the layout of it's sibling word to the right, but I do want the left word to be right aligned, and like that alignment should be set to a space to the left of "Irelnd"